# Pure CSS Accordion Issue - Jump to a Link Inside of the Accordion

Tags: css

I have a website organised as an accordion without Javascript (pure CSS).
Each "accordion-chapter" is quite large.

I would like to jump with a link from outside to inside a chapter (not just the begin => this works with the Accordion) , but to a place inside the chapter.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `div`(not necessarily div can be any tag) element of the chapter an id say

```
<div id="some-chapter">
   ...The Content...
</div>
```

Now, `yourwebsiteurl/#some-chapter` will take you to that chapter

If this is not clear, can you post some code of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Unfortunately,this does not help because of the accordion.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, so that we can know whats going on